# Appropriate Substrate Pallets for voting proposal

Tags: pallet, pallet-contracts, governance

In my custom blockchain, i want to offer a feature where i will provide some proposals to my users. The users can vote on to the proposal they find considerate. To accept the proposal, there will be a threshold. If the number of votes for a specific proposal crosses the threshold the proposal will be accepted.

Is there any pallet you can suggest me to implement this feature.

Answer (score 0):

the feature you are describing can be implemented using the Substrate framework's built-in pallets. The Substrate ecosystem offers a few pallets that can be useful for creating a voting or governance system. Here are some pallets you might consider using or modifying for your specific needs:

**Democracy Pallet**

The Democracy pallet is a built-in Substrate pallet that allows for on-chain governance through proposals and referenda. Users can propose motions, vote on them, and once a proposal crosses a certain threshold of approval, it can be enacted. The Democracy pallet handles time-locking of tokens, voting periods, and other aspects of democratic governance.

**Collective Pallet**

The Collective pallet is designed for multi-signature governance, but it could be adapted for your needs. It allows a group of accounts to make decisions through voting. While it's more often used for council governance, you could use it as a basis for a more general voting system.

**Treasury Pallet**

Though not directly a voting system, the Treasury pallet is often used in combination with the Democracy or Collective pallets to propose spending of communal funds. Proposals can be put up for a vote, and if they pass the threshold, the funds are allocated accordingly.

**Custom Pallet**

If none of the existing pallets meet your specific requirements, you can also create a custom pallet. Since you're already a blockchain developer working on Substrate, you'll find it quite straightforward to develop a pallet tailored to your needs. You can take inspiration from the existing pallets and add your custom logic.

**Steps to Implement:**

Choose or Customize Pallet: Decide whether to use an existing pallet like Democracy or Collective, or create a new one.

**Add to Runtime:** Once you have the pallet, include it in your runtime by modifying your `runtime/src/lib.rs` or equivalent.

**Configuration:** Configure the pallet's parameters such as voting period, enactment period, and thresholds.

**Testing:** Use Substrate's testing framework to ensure that the pallet works as expected.

**Front-end:** Build the user interface for proposal creation and voting using Polkadot.js or your own custom front-end.

**Deployment:** Finally, include your new pallet in a runtime upgrade and deploy it.

By carefully selecting and configuring these pallets, you can build a robust voting system tailored to the needs of your custom blockchain.